# python randomly sort items of the same value

Tags: python

This is a bit tricky and I couldn't come up with anything concise.

I have a list of tuples sorted by an item of the tuple. It's possible for these items to have the same value, so something like this:

```
a = [(a,1), (b,1), (c, 1), (d,2), (e,2), (f,2)]
```

What I'm looking for, is a way to randomize the order of all the 1's and 2's within their own sets. This is to replace a bit of mysql:

```
ORDER BY num_of_hotdogs DESC, rand()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could sort items by a tuple consisting of themselves and then a random number. If `v_1 < v_2`, `(v_1, random.random()) < (v_2, random.random())`; if `v_1 == v_2`, it'll fall back to comparing on the random number.

```
sorted(a, key=lambda v: (v, random.random()))
```

Comment: .... seriously? I'm still green when it comes to python but stuff like this just really makes my day.

Comment: Note: sorted(a, key=lambda v: (v[1], random.random())) you need to specify the index on v, but yeah.

Comment: Right, sorry, you need to "stack" that key function with whatever key function you would've used previously.